# Blazor WebAssembly how to load multiple dynamic dlls?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly standalone application which need to add dynamic dll's to a service, which then can be used in the `App.razor` to add the assemblies to the `AdditionalAssemblies` parameter.

I am this far that it works when you define the exact file to download into the stream. However, I want to have a list of dynamic assemblies instead, which are all located in the `wwwroot/Pages` folder.

This is what I have inside `Program.cs` of the Blazor WebAssembly app:

**Program.cs**

```
public static async Task Main (String[] args) {
  List<Assembly> m_DynamicAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
  var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

  builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

  HttpClient http = new HttpClient() {
    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
  };

  // Load static assemblies
  DynamicAssemblies dynamicAssemblies = new DynamicAssemblies();
  Stream dllStream = await http.GetStreamAsync("/Pages/Test.dll");
  if (dllStream != null) {
    Assembly assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(dllStream);
    if (assembly != null) {
      m_DynamicAssemblies.Add(assembly);
    }
  }
  if (m_DynamicAssemblies != null && m_DynamicAssemblies.Count > 0) {
    dynamicAssemblies.DynamicAssemblies = m_DynamicAssemblies;
  }
  builder.Services.AddSingleton(dynamicAssemblies)
  ... << registering other stuff here >> ...
}
```

The `DynamicAssemblies` is a model class containing a `List<Assembly>` getter.

How can I get all dlls from the `/Pages/` directory instead of hardcoding them? The dll name can change.

I tried something like `var dllsStream = await http.GetStreamAsync("/Pages/*.dll");` but no result there. I need to loop trough the Assemblies and add them to the service.

Comment: [Lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is described in the docs. The libraries are stored and loaded from the *server*, not the client. The names are already known, not hard-coded, so `*.dll` serves no purpose beyond enabling script injection. The assembly names in the example aren't hard-coded.

Comment: I think it was clear that the names of the `dlls` are _not_ known, so I can't add them to the project file:

"The `{ASSEMBLY NAME}` placeholder is the name of the assembly. The .dll file extension is required."

Comment: In that case there's a misunderstanding on how JavaScript, WASM and by extension Blazor work. This isn't a desktop application and the modules aren't data. You can only load modules specified in the apps manifest. That manifest is generated during compilation and contains the signature of the modules, to ensure they aren't tampered with.

Comment: Another misconception is `wwwroot`. That's not a local folder. Anything that isn't bundled in the SPA itself will have to be retrieved from the server. And the server already knows what Blazor assemblies are available. Instead of trying to load them all with `*.dll` why not ask the server for a list of modules?

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? What is the actual problem to which you think dynamic loading is the answer? Creating a composite SPA perhaps? With separate pages/sections loaded from different modules?

Comment: We have a RCL containing a lot of components. We target that RCL with both a `Blazor Server` project and a `_standalone_ Blazor WebAssembly` project. So the wasm is not Hosted, and therefore has no `server`. I am totally aware that `wwwroot` is not a local folder, hence I am using `HttpClient` for wasm, and using `Directory` system for Blazor Server.

Comment: Like I explained, I am registering the loaded Assemblies in a service which I then add to the `AdditionalAssemblies` parameter in `App.razor`. I could define the different dlls in `appsettings.json` and then use that to download the streams, but that is not the dynamic feature I seek.